Algebraization of complex manifolds
To a complex torus $T$, one can associate an abelian variety $A$ and a morphism $\varphi$ universal in the obvious way : for any projective variety $X$ and any morphism $f : T \rightarrow X$, there is an unique morphism $g : A \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ \varphi = f$.
There is several relations between $T$ and $A$. Among them, the morphism $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism between there fraction fields. So we could define a posteriori $A$ to be a smooth projective variety such that $\mathbb{C}(A)=\mathbb{C}(T)$, but this is a really bad definition, because $A$ is then defined only up to a birational transform, and it is not clear that it should be an abelian variety. The correct proof use linear algebra on theta functions, and in fact for most tori $\mathbb{C}(T)=\mathbb{C}$, so we just find a point, but the theorem gives a construction for the (rare) intermediate cases.
Question
Is there another family of varieties with this universal property (for an algebraic variety also in this family) ?

It is obvious for curves/Fano/Strong Calabi-Yau... because they are always algebraic.
We can restrict to kähler varieties, thus the only obstruction for $X$ to be algebraic is that $deg(\mathbb{C}(X))<dim(X)$ (Moishezon).

So if we note $X_{alg}$ for the algebraization of $X$ and if we want to keep the relation $\mathbb{C}(X)=\mathbb{C}(X_{alg})$, then $X_{alg}$ should always be defined at least up to a birational transform, and we should have a rational map from $X$ to $X_{alg}$.
For tori, once we know that $X$ and $X_{alg}$ are tori, it is known that a rational map is always a morphism (because a torus can not contained a rational curve), so maybe the fact that we have a morphism is specific to tori and I should ask only for a rational map.
Furthermore for a surface $S$, the obstruction to be algebraic is that $deg(\mathbb{C}(S)\leq 1$, so $S_{alg}$ is either a point or a curve, and then every birational map is an isomorphism, so $S_{alg}$ is at least well defined, and it will satisfy the universal property if we construct the rational map $\varphi$, but this last point is not clear to me.

The word family is imprecise here ; but as $dim(X_{alg})=deg(\mathbb{C}(X))<dim(X)$, a family should appear in all dimensions. For instance Fano (I recall this case is trivial) or Calabi-Yau.
So the case of $K3$ surfaces is already unclear : as I explain earlier, for surfaces we can find some kind of $S_{alg}$, but to stay in the family of Calabi-Yau varieties, it should be an elliptic curve or a point, which is non trivial (and probably false).

Any remark would be welcomed

Sorry for my ignorance on complex geometry. By "restricting to Kähler", do you mean that being Kähler is a condition (in place of an extra structure)? This is relevant to the question in the sense that, if there is an extra structure (e.g. a Hermitian metric), then it seems natural to require that $g$ preserves this structure.

As Kähler + Moishezon (the condition on the degree of transcendance of the fraction field) = algebraic, I think it is already a deep question to measure the defect of algebricity with the extra assumption of Kahler ( so we just have to correct the Moishezon part).
Each algebraic variety has this kähler structure, but usually we dont ask that holomorphic map respect it, because there is a lot of structure possibles (at least in this kind of question I think it is not relevant).

"To a complex torus , one can associate an abelian variety  ..."  — But wait, isn't that only for complex tori satisfying the Riemann conditions?

@DanielAsimov I don't claim that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. The Riemann relations ensure you that it is sometimes the case. But for a non algebraic torus, $dim(A)<dim(T)$ (for $T$ very general $A$ is a point) so we can't hope for a biholomorphism.

Ueno, Classification Theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex manifolds, p. 25: an algebraic reduction of an irreducible and reduced compact complex analytic variety $X$ is a morphism $X^*\to Y$ where $X^*$ is smooth and bimeromorphic to $X$, $Y$ is a projective manifold and $X^*\to Y$ yields an isomorphism of the fields of meromorphic functions. This is perhaps what you meant by $X_{\text{alg}}$ anyway, but I suppose it gives a reference. Of course, it is defined and unique only up to bimeromorphic equivalence, so maybe not what you are looking for.

Thanks for the reference. As I suspected, the fact that everything is a morphism is really specific to the case of tori because here the birational geometry is essentially trivial. Also for surfaces the remark 12.7 + theorem 12.4 seems to explain everything I want.
Anyway, it is still impressive that for tori we always find an abelian variety. It would be nice to find the same result for hyperkahler, but I am probably to naive.
